# Adding a lot of responses with google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to make a script that will add a lot of(about 1500) CV and candidate info as a response to a form. I have the information as a google spreadsheet. I linked it to form but i can only manage responses. Even if i change the spreadsheet(or add), no update will happen in the form. I am adding lines but no responses added. Is that possible? I saw 2-3 questions about that but they were old and i am still trying to get answers. This is my internship project and i have not much time left. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're concerned with the stats of the responses visible from within the form?

Comment: Nope. I want to add response via Form&Sheet API. I have 1500 lines of info, every line must be a response. I need to add them as response but instead of doing it with my hands, i wrote a program.  I linked the sheet to form. But i couldn't add the lines as responses.

Comment: if you post your code then people can help link the two or work out why what you have isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

For example you can upload your answers to a spreadsheet, get them in array and submit through [FormResponce](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) object (for that you need to use [Form#createResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse()) ).

I didn't test this code, but as far as I understand something like this should work for you.

```
var ANSWER_SHEET_ID = "xxx";
var FORM_ID = "yyy";

function myFunction() {
  const answers = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ANSWERS_SHEET_ID)
                       .getSheetByName('answers')  //Let's say that sheet is named
                       .getRange(answerSheet.getLastRow(), answerSheet.getLastColumn())
                       .getValues() //get it as the Array
                       .slice(1); //slice the header row if it exists in your answer_sheet

  const form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);

  const formResponse = form.createResponse();
  const items = form.getItems();

  for(var i=0, len=answers.length; i<len; ++i){
    //you have to define types of your Items like this
    formResponse.withItemResponse(items[0].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][0])) //for Text Item
                .withItemResponse(items[1].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse(answers[i][1])) //Multiple Choice Item
                .withItemResponse(items[2].asScaleItem().createResponse(parseInt(answers[i][2]))) //for Scale Item !! requires integer as a response
                .submit();
  }
}
```

Just be careful, some items require Integer as a response while others expect String etc.

Comment: It worked? I have almost 60 item in my sheet, i  tried for everyone of them. Responses are added, but the fields are empty. But still, you solved the real problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kristianth, share your script with us =) we'll see what's going on)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you guys, i could add an item as response. It is the great start for me! Here is the code i have written:

```
const answers = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-2, sheet.getLastColumn()-2);


var formResponse = new Array(answers.length);
for(var i =0; i < answers.length; ++i)
formResponse[i] = form.createResponse();

const items = form.getItems();

for(var i=0, len=answers.length; i<len; ++i){

   formResponse[i]
   .withItemResponse(items[1].asDateItem().createResponse(answers[i][0]))
   .withItemResponse(items[2].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][1]))
   .withItemResponse(items[3].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][2]))
   .withItemResponse(items[4].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][3]))
   .withItemResponse(items[5].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][4]))
   .withItemResponse(items[6].asDateItem().createResponse(answers[i][5]))
   .withItemResponse(items[7].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][6]))
   .withItemResponse(items[8].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][7]))
   .withItemResponse(items[9].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][8]))
   .withItemResponse(items[10].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][9]))
   .withItemResponse(items[11].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][10]))

   .withItemResponse(items[12].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][11]))
   .withItemResponse(items[13].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][12]))
   .withItemResponse(items[14].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][13]))
   .withItemResponse(items[15].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][14]))
   .withItemResponse(items[16].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][15]))

   .withItemResponse(items[18].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][16]))

   //.withItemResponse(items[19].asCheckboxItem().createResponse(answers[i][17]))

   .withItemResponse(items[21].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][18]))
   .withItemResponse(items[22].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][19]))
   .withItemResponse(items[23].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][20]))
   .withItemResponse(items[24].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][21]))
   .withItemResponse(items[25].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][22]))
   .withItemResponse(items[26].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][23]))

   .withItemResponse(items[28].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][24]))
   .withItemResponse(items[29].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][25]))
   .withItemResponse(items[30].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][26]))
   .withItemResponse(items[31].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][27]))
   .withItemResponse(items[32].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][28]))
   .withItemResponse(items[33].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][29]))

   .withItemResponse(items[35].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][30]))
   .withItemResponse(items[36].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][31]))       
   .withItemResponse(items[37].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][32]))
   .withItemResponse(items[38].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][33]))



   .withItemResponse(items[40].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][34]))
   .withItemResponse(items[41].asListItem().createResponse(answers[i][35]))
   .withItemResponse(items[42].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][36]))

   .withItemResponse(items[44].asDateItem().createResponse(answers[i][37]))
   .withItemResponse(items[45].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][38]))
   .withItemResponse(items[46].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][39]))

   .withItemResponse(items[48].asDateItem().createResponse(answers[i][40]))
   .withItemResponse(items[49].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][41]))
   .withItemResponse(items[50].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][42]))

   .withItemResponse(items[52].asDateItem().createResponse(answers[i][43]))
   .withItemResponse(items[53].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][44]))
   .withItemResponse(items[54].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][45]))

   .withItemResponse(items[55].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][47]))
   .withItemResponse(items[56].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][48]))
   .withItemResponse(items[57].asParagraphTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][49]))
   .withItemResponse(items[58].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][50]))
   .withItemResponse(items[59].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][51]))
   .withItemResponse(items[60].asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][52])) 
   .submit();

}
```

I did as Rudolf says.  Thanks for the help. If anyone knows about adding more that one responses, i'd be very grateful for that.