# Prefill Google Forms spreadsheed with results from other sheet

Tags: forms, google-sheets, google-forms

I've tried figuring this out but without success until now, I want to create a new Google Forms spreadsheet, and already fill it with some data.

The reason I want this is because at this moment I have one spreadsheet with info from 2015, 2016,2017 and I want to split it to each quarter to view the **responses**, including the nice charts.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45049484/1595451

Comment: Seems its been answered. in a different thread/question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100459/prefill-a-google-form-link-using-data-from-spreadsheet-with-text-masking